# Android - Geocoder is not comprehensive

Tags: android

I'm using geocoder to getting the address from latitude and longitude but the JSON that I get does not very comprehensive, for example, I get just the alley and city but I can't get the street name or the area name. There must be some other way to implement something like this but more comprehensive. This is my code:

```
Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> addresses;
geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());

try {
   addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(currentLatLng.latitude, currentLatLng.longitude, 1);
   String text = addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: did you see this? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html

Comment: @an_droid_dev yes, I examine whole of the Json response but I can't get what I want as I explained.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Latitude, Longitude,1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
        String address1 = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
        String address2 = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
        String address3 = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(3); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the [Geocoding web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) as an alternative?

Example:

```
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY

{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            .
            .
            .
```